# Расставить на UIButton тайтл слева, а картинку справа с некоторыми паддингами

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Нужно, чтобы у кнопки тайтл был с левой стороны с паддингом 20pt, а изображение с правой стороны с паддингом 20pt:

1. прописываю поля title и image для UIButton
2. semantic устанавливаю в Force-Right-to-Left, чтобы изображение было справа, а тайтл слева
3. задав content insets (left) или title insents (left) можно сделать нужный отступ для тайтла
4. как выровнять изображение по правой стороне кнопки с паддингом 20?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам проще будет добавить `UIImageView` поверх кнопки с необходимыми constraints, чем настраивать кнопку.

Но если все же хотите так сделать с кнопкой, то задавайте кодом необходимые insets, в методе `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, так как если кнопка пропорциональна ширине экрана, то для каждого размера экрана значения будут свои и в Interface Builder не настроить.